# Comparar valor de dois campos com jquery

Tags: html, jquery

Estou com um problema na comparação de valores de dois campos `input`.
Quero que aconteça uma ação se o valor que está a ser inserido for inferior ao valor do `input` oculto.

Imaginem que o valor do anterior tem que ser inferior ao valor do campo que estou a inserir no momento, e o valor do anterior é 8594. Se inserir 85939 ele considera este valor inferior ao anterior.

Vejam o código:

```
<div class="form-group">

<label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Contador  Atual</label>
<br />
Valor Anterior: <span class="anterior">8594</span>
<input type="hidden" class="vant" value="8594">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Introduzir Valor Do Contador">
```

```
$('input[type="text"]').blur(function() {

    var campoV = $(this).parent().find('.anterior');
    var thisvalue = $(this).val();
    var anteriorValue = $(this).parent().find('.vant').val();

    if(thisvalue < anteriorValue) {
        campoV.css("color", "red");
    } else{
        campoV.css("color", "black");
        //insere valor na base de dados!!
    }    

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer desta forma, mudei algumas coisa, como por exemplo, há dois elementos com id igual, não pode haver em uma página dois elementos com o mesmo id, e alterei os ids para ficarem mais sugestivos.

Segue o código abaixo comentado.

```js
$('#valor-contador').blur(function() {

  //Seleciona os elementos
  var elementoValorAnterior = $("#valor-anterior");
  var elementoValorContador = $("#valor-contador");
  var elementoValorAnteriorVisao = $("#valor-anterior-visao");

  //Converte os valores de string para inteiro
  var valorAnterior = parseInt(elementoValorAnterior.val());
  var valorContador = parseInt(elementoValorContador.val());
  
  //Verifica se o valor anterior e maior que o valor do contador
  if(valorAnterior > valorContador){
    elementoValorAnteriorVisao.css("color", "red");
  }else{
    elementoValorAnteriorVisao.css("color", "black");
    //insere valor na base de dados!!
  }
  
  //Caso queira atualizar os valores
  //elementoValorAnterior.val(valorContador);
  //elementoValorAnteriorVisao.text(valorContador);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Contador  Atual</label>
  <br />
  Valor Anterior: 
  <span id="valor-anterior-visao">8594</span>
  <input id="valor-anterior" type="hidden" value="8594">
  <input id="valor-contador" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Introduzir Valor Do Contador">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que sua comparação está sendo feita como se o valor fosse uma "string".
Neste caso "85939" é menor que "8594", pois o início "8594" é maior que "8593" e depois vem o "9".

Para comparar o numeral, deve converter para número, veja o exemplo:

```js
// comparação como strings
console.log("85939" < "8594");

// aqui, comparando como números
console.log(Number("85939") < ("8594"));
```